# Bash sed command with sed itself as replacement, quotes not outputted

Tags: bash

I need to modify the content of a file, with the following sed command (which works fine):

```
sed -i 's@date.timezone.*@'"date.timezone = $TZ"'@' $PHP_INI_DIR/conf.d/symfony.ini
```

This line should be injected in a script before the `exec`:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e

exec "$@"
```

So i need another sed to say "replace before `exec`":

```
sed '/exec/i \sed -i 's@date.timezone.*@'"date.timezone = $TZ"'@' $PHP_INI_DIR/conf.d/symfony.ini\n' docker-php-entrypoint
```

The problem are quotes which are not **outputted**:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e

sed -i s@date.timezone.*@"date.timezone = $TZ"@ $PHP_INI_DIR/conf.d/symfony.ini

exec
```

Putting a backslash `\` before `'s@date.timezone` does nothing. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a shell issue. The shell does "quote removal", so you need to study how quotes behave in the shell. Single quotes can't be nested nor escaped. You have to end the single quoted string to insert a single quote.

```
sed '/exec/i \sed -i '\''s@date.timezone.*@'\''"date.timezone = $TZ"'\''@'\'' $PHP_INI_DIR/conf.d/symfony.ini\n'
```

Comment: Same problem as @Salim answer, when I issue the command the shell doesn't ouput. Seems stuck waiting for termination.

Comment: You need to add the rest of the parameters (e.g. the file name).

Comment: Sorry, you right, i noticed just after writing the comment.. thanks, i'm testing it!

Answer (score 1):

You can use double quotes within single quotes and vice versa to escape the quotes:

```
sed '/exec/i \sed -i '"'"'s@date.timezone.*@"date.timezone = $TZ"@' $PHP_INI_DIR/conf.d/symfony.ini\n'"'"' docker-php-entrypoint
```

This way, the single quotes are escaped within the single quotes and the double quotes are used within the escaped single quotes.

Comment: Thanks but it seems not working. When I issue the command, the shell seems to wait for another one. (doesn't print output)

Comment: It's possible that the command is not being properly terminated. You can try adding a backslash \ at the end of the sed command to indicate that the command continues on the next line:

sed "/exec/i sed -i 's@date.timezone.*@'"'date.timezone = \$TZ'"'@' $PHP_INI_DIR/conf.d/symfony.ini\\" docker-php-entrypoint